# Resize transparent image (UIImage) without getting black background

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to resize my UIImage which contains transparent image using next solution but it returns image without transparency, instead that transparent area become black color

```
extension UIImage{

    func resizeImageWith(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {

        let horizontalRatio = newSize.width / size.width
        let verticalRatio = newSize.height / size.height

        let ratio = max(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio)
        let newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * ratio, height: size.height * ratio)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, true, 0)
        draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: newSize))
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage!
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext - Split image into two creates a black background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939494/uigraphicsgetimagefromcurrentimagecontext-split-image-into-two-creates-a-black)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting the opaque property to true. If you would like it to be transparent you need to set it to false:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0)
```

Note that `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` returns an optional image so you should change your return type also and you can use defer to end your context after returning the result:

```
extension UIImage {
    func resizeImageWith(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        let horizontalRatio = newSize.width / size.width
        let verticalRatio = newSize.height / size.height
        let ratio = max(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio)
        let newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * ratio, height: size.height * ratio)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}
```